# TypeError: SetPoint argument 1: integer argument expected, got float

Tags: python, vtk

can someone help me with this?

```
pts.InsertPoint(fl[i+1][j+1][k+1], xx[0][i+1], yy[0][j+1], zz[0][k+1])
TypeError: InsertPoint argument 1: integer argument expected, got float
```

fl is supposed to have float, I have the array from real world experiment, I can't change the values to int.

Is this an issue related to InsertPoint, is it only taking int? Can someone help me fix it?

Also, I don't have experience in Python, never wrote a program, this is the first program I am working with, I made changes to an old program to get it work for my purposes, but can't figure out what I did wrong

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not whether or not fl is composed of floats. The problem is that the method signature for InsertPoint expects each value to be an int.

From the python documentation:

```
exception TypeError:
```

> Raised when an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type. The    associated value is a string giving details about the type mismatch.

This information is clearly available in the error message you pasted - it has both the exception type (`TypeError`) and the object by which it was thrown (`InsertPoint`). Had you accidentally included a float in your array indexers, the exception would have been thrown by something other than InsertPoint.

In the future, you should do some research on Google based on your exception error. I'm not telling you anything you couldn't find there.

If you still want to use InsertPoints, you have two options:

1. You can use the (int) cast to truncate edit: the first of your arguments to the whole, integer value (1.2 truncates to 1, 2.67 to 2, etc.), like so:

   `int(fl[i+1][j+1][k+1])`
2. You can do #1, but round the value to the nearest integer value, like below (keep in mind that you'll need to import Math):

   `int(Math.Round(fl[i+1][j+1][k+1]))`

Comment: Do you know of something similar to InsertPoint, that will do the same job but will be ok with floats?

Comment: The problem is that I need to have floats. I don't necessarily need to use insertpoint, though

Comment: @aregak This is a vtk type? Can you point me towards the specific namespace/library in which that type exists? Also, can you try replacing InsertPoints() with several InsertNextPoint() calls?

Comment: yes, this is vtk type! I don't think InsertNextPoint() will be efficient in my case, my array is 81x81x61 size

Comment: Note that only the first argument is expected to be an int. The other three are floats.

Comment: @andybauer Thanks - I'd looked a bit for the vtk documentation, but mostly I was hoping he'd provide it to me. If you want to make an answer explaining the issue specifically w/r/t InsertPoints, I'll gladly upvote it. I'ma ctually going to delete this answer because it looks like the problem has significantly less to do with the OPs misunderstanding of method signatures and more with the library details, which I know little about.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation of vtkpoints::InsertPoint you will see that the expected arguments are (id,x,y,z). You use this method when you have to want to set the value of the point at position id (that's why it must be an integer). http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPoints.html#ab7f990c73fb291737abe4203994ce2a2

from the python shell, you can also check `help(pts.InsertPoint)` - but since these are wrapped objects sometimes the help appears a bit obscure.

The method InsertNextPoint, instead, just requires x,y,z and can be used as you are doing. It doesn't require an explicit id because it will just your point at the end

Specifically for python , you could be interested also in  vtk.util.numpy_support which makes conversions between numpy and vtk elements easier (you can convert your points from numpy to a vtkdoublearray, then assign it to a vtkpoints with the method setdata )

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping each or your values in `int()`, like so:

```
pts.InsertPoint(int(fl[i+1][j+1][k+1]), int(xx[0][i+1]), int(yy[0][j+1]), int(zz[0][k+1]))
```